# Regex to match different sets for each character using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, set, character

The pattern is 9 characters as such:

Character 1: letters w, g, a, b and c only

Character 2: letters p, m and x only

Character 3, 4 and 5: HEX 0-9 a-f only

Character 6: dash only

Character 7, 8 and 9: HEX 0-9 and a-f only

Here are some examples of names that match this pattern:

gm9a1-8ac

bp7e3-2ab

ax3c1-51e

How can I create a regex that matches?

I started with one that covers only letters, numbers and dashes but I need to make it satisfy the rules above.

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$/
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([wgabc][pmx][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{3})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP5dA6/1)

Explanation:
`[wgabc]` letters w, g, a, b and c only
`[pmx]` letters p, m and x only
`[0-9a-f]{3}` HEX 0-9 a-f only, 3 times